# How to get process id from output of ps -ef | grep 'tomcat'?

Tags: linux, tomcat

I want to kill tomcat process and hence used command -

```
ps -ef | grep 'tomcat'
```

and it returns following big output and there I can see 3 pids -

```
oracle    76220 218600  3 May16 pts/2    00:40:14 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -DcoreJMX=true -DqueryJMX=true -javaagent:/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco141.exec,append=false,includes=com.eqtechnologic.* -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/logs/gcLogs.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -classpath /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Dcatalina.home=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
oracle   138680 219157  0 15:46 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
oracle   187823 161915  1 May16 pts/1    00:29:01 //bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -DcoreJMX=true -DqueryJMX=true -javaagent:/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco-0.7.5.201505241946/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/oracle/Jacoco/jacoco141.exec,append=false,includes=com.eqtechnologic.* -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/logs/gcLogs.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -classpath /home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Dcatalina.home=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/oracle/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

But I am confused which one is pid of tomcat. Can someone please help me to understand how to read this output which will help me to get pid of tomcat?

If I guessed correctly, is `138680` pid of tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively , a more simple way is to use the [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/jcmd.html) command from the SDK which will directly print out the process ID of all the JVM processes likes:

```
20720 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd
13066 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

13066 is the process ID of the tomcat in this example.

To further confirm that this process is really that tomcat process that you want to kill, you can further check its its main class and the JVM argument that is used to start this process by :

```sh
$ jcmd 13066 VM.command_line
```

Comment: Output of `jcmd` is more clear than `ps -ef | grep catalina`. Thanks for all the details added in answer!

Answer (score 2):

76220 and 187823 are the PID of tomcat server. You can use the below command to check the main tomcat process.

```
pgrep -fl catalina
```

Comment: It returned to pids. How to identify which is of main tomcat process?

Comment: Above command will return tomcat PID file

`[test@test test]pgrep -fl catalina`
`4692 java`.


4692 is the process ID of the tomcat in this example. Alternatively you can use jcmd command which contains "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start" main statup class. 


`[test@test test]# jcmd`
`4692 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`
`7637 sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd`